# Unable to read content from tempfile

Tags: python

python: 3.6.8
code:

```
temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
getui.download(path=f"{path}{file}", localPath=temp_file.name)
temp_file.seek(0)
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
item = {"file": temp_file, "filename": file}
queue.put(item)
```

I cannot read anything from `tempfile`, but can read its content using open, as another file:

```sh
ipdb> temp_file.read(10)
b''
ipdb> temp_file.seek(0)
0
ipdb> temp_file.read(10)
b''
ipdb> f = open(temp_file.name)
ipdb> f.read(10)
'6C1D91DB-F'
ipdb>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I am guessing that `getui.download` is deleting and recreating the file, so it will be writing to a different inode than the one which Python has open (which no longer has any associated directory entry). When you reopen the file, you are now looking at the same inode as was written by `getui.download`.

Comment: If you can please post a minimal reproducible example (specifically here, show where your `getui` comes from), then it will be possible to verify this.

Comment: @alaniwi `getui.download` method called `boto3.session.Session.client` object's `download_file` method, the method will download file from `path` to `localPath` by default bucket

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted enough detail to be able to reproduce this, but the likelihood is that your `getui.download` is deleting and recreating the file, so it will be writing to a different inode than the one which Python has open (which no longer has any associated directory entry). When you reopen the file, you are now looking at the same inode as was written by `getui.download`.

To demonstrate by means of example what is likely to be happening, here is an example in which (in Linux) some basic file operations are performed to do a delete-and-recreate (using ctrl-Z to temporarily suspend the Python process while this is done):

```
>>> temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

>>> temp_file.name
'/tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul'

>>> os.stat(temp_file.name).st_ino  # <=== look at the inode number
42

>>> [[ctrl-Z pressed here]]
[1]+  Stopped                 python3

$ ls -li /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul 
42 -rw------- 1 myuser mygroup 0 Aug 14 10:33 /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul

$ rm /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul   # <=== delete

$ echo hello > /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul  # <=== create new file 

$ ls -li /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul  # <=== see the new inode number
41 -rw-rw-r-- 1 myuser mygroup 6 Aug 14 10:34 /tmp/tmpo4j5k0ul

$ fg   # <=== return to the python session 
python3

>>> os.fstat(temp_file.fileno()).st_ino  # <=== recheck the inode number
42   # <=== still the old one

>>> temp_file.seek(0)
0

>>> temp_file.read()
b''

>>> f = open(temp_file.name)  # <=== reopen from the filename

>>> os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_ino  # <=== recheck the inode number
41  # <=== the new one this time

>>> f.read()
'hello\n'
```

Regarding how to fix this, you might find that your `getui.download` has an option to pass a file object rather than a file name, or at least to open to an existing file for writing rather than deleting and recreating it.  Again, without exact details of where `getui.download` comes from, it is hard to give definite advice, but this will be the principle that you need to follow.

Comment: `getui.download` method called `boto3.session.Session.client` object's `download_file method`, the method will download file from `path` to `localPath` by default bucket. And I'll try your method, thx.